Swift でボタンを押すたび TextView を切り替えて一つだけ表示されるようにしたい
swift初心者で、こちらに投稿することも初めてです。
インターネットで調べてもわからなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきます。
swiftでオリジナルアプリを作っています。
ボタンを押すたびに、TextView1 → TextView2 → TextView3 → TextView4 と、TextViewが一つだけ表示される方法を教えてください。
こちらの方法でもエラーが出てしまい、うまくいきませんでした。
キーボードの「次へ」を押して、次のTextField,TextViewに移動する処理を簡単にしたFormChangeableを作ってみた
インターネットで6時間調べても分からなかったため、こちらに書き込ませていただきました。
追加
この方法で取り敢えずできたのですが、もっと良い方法があれば教えてください。
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()　
if false {
textView1.text = Array[１]
textView2.text = Array[２]
textView3.text = Array[3]
}
@IBAction func btnTap(sender: UIButton) {
tapCount += 1
if tapCount == 1 {
textView1.text = Array[１]
}
if tapCount == 2 {
textView1.text = " "
textView2.text = Array[２]
}

